# How can I make a single line to code to run once in a loop and only run the next line of code until the previous has ran once?

Tags: lua

Script code is for a robot and consist of a block of codes that are waypoints to drop products. I want to save lines by running a single line of code only once and return to the top of the loop and only run the next line of code until the previous line has run once.

```
function pim60()
script_common_interface("SICKCamera","takePhoto")
script_common_interface("SICKCamera","getResult")
Located = script_common_interface("SICKCamera","partLocated")
end


function intermediatemoves()
    X = script_common_interface("SICKCamera","getXposition")
    Y = script_common_interface("SICKCamera","getYposition")
    R = script_common_interface("SICKCamera","getRotation")
    z_offset = 0.24

    local offset_pose = {}
    table.insert(offset_pose,X)
    table.insert(offset_pose,Y)
    table.insert(offset_pose,z_offset)

    camera_rz = rpy2quaternion({d2r(-180.0), d2r(0.0), d2r(-90.0) + d2r(R)})

    move_joint(get_target_pose(offset_pose,camera_rz,false,{0.0, 0.0, 0.0},{1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}),true)

    z_grab = 0.17

    local grab_pose = {}
    table.insert(grab_pose,X)
    table.insert(grab_pose,Y)
    table.insert(grab_pose,z_grab)

    move_line(get_target_pose(grab_pose,camera_rz,false,{0.0, 0.0, 0.0},{1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0}),true)

     set_step_breakpoint()
     --(Logic tree item : Gripper) Gripper
     script_common_interface("Gripper", "set_robotiq_param|9, 155, 255, 255, true")
     set_step_breakpoint()
     --(Logic tree item : Move) Movedrp
     --(Logic tree item : Waypoint) Waypoint01
     move_joint({1.047662, -0.552625, -1.753926, 0.374278, -1.571027, 0.588803}, true)
     set_step_breakpoint()
     --(Logic tree item : Waypoint) Waypoint02
     move_joint({2.307135, 0.811214, -0.349017, 0.045296, -1.569157, -0.006474}, true)
     set_step_breakpoint()
end


function returntohome()
      --WAYPOINT FOR COLLISION AVOIDANCE
      --(Logic tree item : Waypoint) Waypoint02
      move_joint({2.307135, 0.811214, -0.349017, 0.045296, -1.569157, -0.006474}, true)
      set_step_breakpoint()
      --!!HOME POSITION JOINT 5 CAN AFFECT PICK COLLISION WITH PART
      --(Logic tree item : Waypoint) Waypointhome
      move_joint({1.321444, -0.626547, -2.252496, -0.137991, -1.518901, -0.006779}, true)
      set_step_breakpoint()
end

--Open gripper and home
   script_common_interface("Gripper", "set_robotiq_param|9, 0, 255, 255, false")
   --!!HOME POSITION JOINT 5 CAN AFFECT PICK COLLISION WITH PART
   --(Logic tree item : Waypoint) Waypointhome
   move_joint({1.321444, -0.626547, -2.252496, -0.137991, -1.518901, -0.006779}, true)
    set_step_breakpoint()

--LoopA
repeat
pim60()
until (Located == 1)
intermediatemoves()
move_joint({2.337869, 1.478278, 0.177188, -0.416970, -1.569186, -0.006448}, true)
script_common_interface("Gripper", "set_robotiq_param|9, 0, 0, 83, true")
returntohome()

--LoopB
repeat
pim60()
until (Located == 1) 
intermediatemoves()
move_joint({2.145543, 1.478292, 0.177206, -0.416904, -1.569186, -0.006415}, true)
script_common_interface("Gripper", "set_robotiq_param|9, 0, 0, 83, true")
returntohome()

--LoopC
repeat
pim60()
until (Located == 1) 
intermediatemoves()
move_joint({2.020320, 1.478307, 0.177206, -0.416897, -1.569190, -0.006412}, true)
script_common_interface("Gripper", "set_robotiq_param|9, 0, 0, 83, true")
returntohome()

--LoopD
repeat
pim60()
until (Located == 1) 
intermediatemoves()
move_joint({1.845862, 1.478325, 0.177202, -0.416893, -1.569190, -0.006412}, true)
script_common_interface("Gripper", "set_robotiq_param|9, 0, 0, 83, true")
returntohome()
```

This is the code being used now and nowhere close to the function that is desired. I've created 4 repeats "loops" that contains 4 different end position to drop products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cut on the **code duplication** (not line number, that's silly),  you can wrap the duplicated code in a function.

```
function locate()
    repeat
        script_common_interface("SICKCamera","takePhoto")
        script_common_interface("SICKCamera","getResult")
    until (script_common_interface("SICKCamera","partLocated") == 1)
end
```

Further, you'd encapsulate the steps

```
function go_fetch(destination)
    locate()
    intermediatemoves()
    move_joint(destination, true)
    script_common_interface("Gripper", "set_robotiq_param|9, 0, 0, 83, true")
    returntohome()
end
--instead of LoopsABCD
local destinations = {
   {2.020320, 1.478307, 0.177206, -0.416897, -1.569190, -0.006412},
   {2.145543, 1.478292, 0.177206, -0.416904, -1.569186, -0.006415},
   --etc...
   }
for _,d in ipairs(destinations) do
    go_fetch(d)
end
```

You can refactor your other functions to be more concise as well.

p.s. These links may not be immediately related, but I still want to mention them here [1](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/state.html),[2](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/observer.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well you set a flag that helps you remember if you already ran that first line. Or you use the loop counter if you have one.

In many cases it would suffice to simply run that one-time thing befor you enter the loop. But here's a small example:

```
for i = 0, 10 do
  if i == 0 then
     print("Enter bar")
  else
    print("Drink beer no " .. i)
  end
end
```

or

```
 local inBar
 while not drunk do
      if not inBar then
         print("Enter bar")
         inBar = true
      else
        print("Drink another beer")
      end
 end
```

Comment: why not just `if i == 0 then` ?

Comment: @moteus because this is applicable to any kind of loop. of course you can use the loop counter in a for loop as well. I mean if it's the first line of the loop why not simply do it befor entering the loop.